# Не могу понять когда слово "определенно" вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Человек он определенно хороший.
2. Фильм определенно наш.
3. Каротина там определенно не было (Каротин - фамилия чекиста).

Answer (score 4):

В приведенных Вами примерах наречие "несомненно" является обстоятельством и не обособляется, но если его поставить в начало предложения, то такая структура позволяет его обособить. В этом случае оно **относится ко всему высказыванию и считается вводным.**

Определенно (=несомненно), человек он хороший.

Определенно (=несомненно), фильм этот наш.

Третье предложение не получается перестроить.

Answer (score 2):

Во всех Ваших примерах "определённо" не вводное. Оно употреблено в них в значении "наверняка, точно".